# Base Class' Virtual Destructor c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-destructor

I'm confused about virtual destructors. I have read many questions and explanations but i still didn't understand that if there is a derived class from base class, do i need to implement its own destructor even it doesn't have any special operations.

The compiler compiles the code below, but would be there any memory leaks or any problems ?

```
Class Base{
public:
virtual ~Base(){}
};

Class Derived : public Base{
// do i need a special destructor here for Derived ?
}

Base *foo;
foo = new Derived;
delete foo;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors/15903538#15903538 try this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide a destructor for `Derived`, then one gets created automatically.  That automatically created destructor overrides the destructor in `Base`, so it gets called when you delete `foo`.  The automatically created destructor would be equivalent to this:

```
Class Derived : public Base {
  ~Derived() { } // this is what you get if you don't provide your own.
}
```

All destructors, whether they are automatically created or not, will automatically call the destructors of all the members of the class and the destructor of the base class.  So everything gets cleaned up nicely.

Comment: so than there is no need to write `~Derived() { }` within `Derived` class since it's automaticly called and it doesn't make any operations specificly, right ?

Answer (score 1):

No there will be no memory leaks since `Derived` will get it's implicit virtual destructor.